# Redirect to custom URL after login in React

Tags: reactjs

After login, I would like my user to be redirected to his custom page.

In an action, I do this:

```
function login(username, password) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(request({username}));

        userService.login(username, password)
            .then(
                user => {
                    dispatch(success(user));
                },
                error => {
                    dispatch(failure(error));
                    toastr.error('Login failed', error.toString())
                }
            );

        function request(user) {
            return {type: userConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST, user}
        }

        function success(user) {
            history.push(user.state !== "2" ? "/first-connexion" : "/bo/view-as/" + user.id);
            return {type: userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS, user}
        }

        function failure(error) {
            return {type: userConstants.LOGIN_FAILURE, error}
        }
    };
}
```

After login, URL is updated, but nothing is happening. If I refresh page with my custom url, it will work.

How can I do to redirect to custom URL after login ?

Comment: I'd recommend to look at [auth-workflow](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) example for how to potentially handle "private" routes and redirects. No matter what you can always put a `Redirect` component into any component where you want to navigate the user based on some condition, such as values from your store.

Comment: Are you using react-router-dom?